# Trouble Converting string to datetime?

Tags: python, datetime

I have this strings with the format "09-FEB-21 05.19.32.871000000 AM".

```
import datetime
dt_string = "09-FEB-21 05.19.32.871000000 AM" 
format = "%d-%m-%y %H.%M.%S.%f %p"
dt_object = datetime.datetime.strptime(dt_string, format)
```

The above code causes `ValueError("unconverted data remains: %s" %`

```
time data '09-FEB-21 05.19.32.871000000 AM' does not match format '%d-%m-%y %H.%M.%S.%f %p'
```

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `%b` instead of `%m` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)):

```
dt_string = "09-FEB-21 05.19.32.871000000 AM"
print(pd.to_datetime(dt_string, format="%d-%b-%y %H.%M.%S.%f %p"))
```

Prints:

```
2021-02-09 05:19:32.871000
```

---

EDIT: Using only `datetime`: Remove last `000` from the fraction:

```
import re
import datetime

dt_string = "09-FEB-21 05.19.32.871000000 AM"
dt_string = re.sub(r"000(?=\s)", "", dt_string)

format = "%d-%b-%y %H.%M.%S.%f %p"
dt_object = datetime.datetime.strptime(dt_string, format)
print(dt_object)
```

Prints:

```
2021-02-09 05:19:32.871000
```

Comment: OP is not using `pandas` (although this works fine of course)

Comment: Do you know why this format doesn't work with `datetime` module ?

Comment: @MrFuppes There was a `pandas` tag but it got removed.

Comment: @dm2 The fraction needs to be in thousands - `datetime` has problem to parse the string. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks. I am using pandas but was trying to get a datetime string outside of that. Thanks anyways

Comment: what if the nanoseconds aren't zero (e.g. `....871000001`)? sorry for the nit-picking ^^

Comment: @MrFuppes I'd use `dt_string = re.sub(r"\d{3}(?=\s)", "", dt_string)` - so the last nanosecond get lost ¯\_(ツ)_/¯